# Image background color

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image that has some white on the edges, and I want to change the background color of the `div` that the image is contained in. Now when I do this, I can still see the little bit of white surrounding the image, and it looks terrible.

Is there a way I can change the background color of the image to whatever the background color of the `div` is, and would this be the best way to do it? Or does it make more sense just to edit the extra white out of the image.

Comment: if it's a transparent gif/png you should edit the image, you can't change the image itself using javascript. If only IE is affected, google for IE transparency maybe a -ms-filter can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just fix the image.

Comment: What's the easiest way to do this exact - without a good photo editing program?

Comment: You'll need image editing software.  Find a free one or something.  Not sure what state GIMP is in, but it used to be decent.  I'm sure there are a million others.  If I'm understanding right, you just need to erase the white part.

Answer (score 0):

If the image has a transparent background then you can change the background color the same way you would a div.

**Edit** You may also want to check to make sure there is no padding, borders, ect. that would cause this issue to happen

Comment: If the image is transparent, wouldn't the div's background color be seen through the image anyway?

Comment: Sometimes, but not always. You may still need to specify the `background-color` property. Maybe the default is white?

Comment: Yeah maybe I'll give this a shot and see, I guess if not I have to fix the image.